# How to view user object type in table? (pl/sql)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In my programm I need to make own object type - fraction.
I can create it like:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE fraction AS OBJECT (   integer number,     numerator number,    denominator number);
```

Can create table with columns like fraction

```
 CREATE TABLE own_table (first fraction, second fraction);
```

It's all o.k. How to make own view of column like fraction? May be some methods or anything else? Column have type only my fraction. Nessesary to change only view in table for user.

requered result:

```
SELECT * FROM own_table;

+first +++++ second  
1(1/2) ++++  2(49/203)  
3(32/34) ++ 12(3/7)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use dotted notation to access the object members, but it appears you have to use an alias for the table name when selecting.

**You also cannot name a column `integer`.**

You'll need a view on your table if you just want to do a `select * from something`.
eg.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE own_view (first, second) AS 
SELECT ot.first.i || '(' || ot.first.numerator || 
'/' || ot.first.denominator || ')',
ot.second.i || '(' || ot.second.numerator || 
'/' || ot.second.denominator || ')' 
FROM own_table ot;
```

[Fiddle here.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/76808/1)

Also, some [docs](http://www.stanford.edu/dept/itss/docs/oracle/10g/appdev.101/b10807/10_objs.htm#i11073) on accessing Oracle object types.

Comment: You don't understand me. I know how to get part of structur my type.  I need method or way to set view of my type in table.

Comment: For example, when I cal select * from table and my table have record with param 1 2 5. I want that select return 1(2/5)

Comment: I've updated the answer, and fiddle.   ...basically you need a `view` to do this.